# Does cold kill whiteflies and their eggs?

Tags: pests, pest-control, chili

I've discovered some nasty **whiteflies** on my **chili peppers**. I'm keeping my plants indoors. my question is if I expose them to cold outdoor temperatures (below 5 or 10 degrees Celsius) does it kill those whiteflies or not? I haven't found any eggs yet but if there are any, does cold temperatures have an effect on them as well?
Is this a good solution overall?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Whitefly" is actually many different species of insect which cannot be distinguished visually but do not interbreed with each other. It is quite likely that different species have different temperature tolerances.

[This study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4832212/) showed about 90% survival of adult whitefly at 4C, and about 60% survival at 0C. The study did not include eggs or pupae because of "issues of technical feasibility."

[This study](https://site.extension.uga.edu/wilcoxcoag/2018/01/whiteflies-freezing-temperatures/) found it took 3 hours at -6C to kill 90% of adults, 57 hours at -6C to kill 90% of nymphs, and "even longer" to kill eggs.

So I guess the answer to your question is "you will probably kill the peppers before you kill the whitefly".